# What is the recommended backup solution for backup files with weird & funny chars in them?

Tags: backup

What is the recommended backup solution for copying files with weird & funny chars in them? e.g. accented chars, square brackets, ampersands, files beginning with periods in them. I'm using Syncback at the moment to copy files from a server to an external drive running NTFS. Syncback doesn't appear to copy these files and some of them I also cannot copy and paste via windows explorer. Is there any way around this problem?

I'm running Windows XP and Windows Server 2003

\Europe Egypt & Eastern Med Radiance Brilliance \Download3.zip

\ARCHIVE\Tourist Board \for ARCHIVE Folder\af playa cadiz ingles\Imágenes._PREGONDA.tif

\ARCHIVE\Tourist Board \for ARCHIVE Folder._.DS_Store

\ARCHIVE\Tourist Board \Backup\STB DPS [556x340].indd

\ARCHIVE\Tourist Board \af murcia playa INGLES\Im†genes\playa murcia.1.tif

\Vector maps\web pdfs\Summer_2007 \sorrento_capri&amalfi_summer_07 249-266.pdf

\Vector maps\web pdfs\Summer_2007 \summer fc_07 OVERPRINT.pdf

Comment: In your case get as far as you can from the OS: either install `cygwin` and `tar` the directories, or mount the disk on a Linux machine and, again, `tar`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't able to find an alternative backup solution. But I was able to find a workaround. I'm just going to rename the file names and folders by removing the offending characters.

Answer (score 0):

rsync maybe ? What OS are you using ? Windows ?

Answer (score 0):

The "recommended backup solution" is actual backup software. You're using a file-copier that can't handle valid characters, not backup software. You